# Anyone successfully running AppFabric Caching?

Tags: .net, appfabric

I'm running into a problem immediately after doing Start-CacheCluster, my cache service has already stopped. My application log shows the following pairs of errors:

ERROR1:

Application: DistributedCacheService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Fabric.Common.ReleaseAssertException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Common.IOCompletionPortWorkQueue.Invoke(System.Threading.WaitCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Common.IOCompletionPortWorkQueue.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

ERROR2:

Faulting application name: DistributedCacheService.exe, version: 1.0.2912.0, time stamp: 0x4bea6d7b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0x2aa4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb0808ce054c15
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\AppFabric\DistributedCacheService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 13c5102f-73fc-11df-90f5-463500000031

I'm using the RTM and I think everything is configured correctly. I'm on Windows 7 64bit and there is another Windows Server 2008 32bit machine in the cluster. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but after a stop and restart of the cluster everything is working again and I don't get errors anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you come across this error and what he did does not fix it, it is likely that there is a permissions problem.

This error also occurs using SharePoint 2013 - take a look at this post to correct:

http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-appfabric-event-id-1000.html

David Sterling/CSA-CEO Sterling International Consulting Group - http://www.sterling-consulting.com
http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com

Comment: I've been getting error (error code: 1026) like below. I looked at the blog and the issue seems little different. This started happening after service account password was updated (service account used as logon for AppFabric service). Do you know if password should be updated anywhere else too?

********************************************************************************************************
Application: DistributedCacheService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason of the crash was in the bug "Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server crashes when an anonymous client tries to access it.". So I've just installed [Cumulative update package 2 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716015/en-us) and it stopped crashing. 
BTW, there can be more info on the crash in special branch in Event Viewer: Applications And Services Log -> Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-System Services